# slim down Firefox Portable for backup

Tags: firefox, backup, portable

I'm using Firefox Portable from portableapps.com

Occasionally, I want to backup the whole folder for safekeeping, but the backup usually takes very long time. I am guessing the reason is that there are so many tiny files. (a few bits) and I am guessing that removing them will not severely affect functionality.
I am looking for a way to slim it down before backing it up, just to save some backup time.

For my backup purposes, I want to keep my Addon, bookmark, and History.

Can anyone tell me which folder I can safely remove to get rid of those numerous tiny files and still keeps firefox portable functionality?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: How are you doing the backup? I regularly backup my own profile (with 7Zip, maximum compression) and it takes roughly less than a minute. I wouldn't recommend you to take away any folder. Where do you have your Firefox Portable (is it in a pen drive?) and how big (in terms of data) is it?

Comment: I went into the folders and found it is one of my addon that is large and shattered, it is called Zotero, a reference tool and it is 1.2Gb, now I think it is not the firefox problem but the addon's problem. So I think I will back up separately from now on

Comment: From what I've seen in the Zotero web page, it seems as though it caches all relevant piece of information it finds online. Although I never used it, research papers can be as big as 20MB so if you've been picking up several research, it would account for the size. I would suggest you to search their forums for solutions on how to "shrink" or better backup your research.

Answer (score 1):

It turn out that the huge size comes from a plug-in I am using: Zotero

A lot of pdf research papers were stored under my folder.

This IS NOT a general Firefox Portable issue.